# Почему код работает не полностью?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста в чём проблема, есть код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var id = $("input[name='ik_payment_id']").val();
        var url = $("input[name='url']").val();
        var image = $("input[name='image']").val();
        var plan = $("input[name='plan']").val();

        $.post("ban_inter.php", {cmd:"add_200", id:id, url:url, image:image, plan:plan});
    });
});
```

Так-вот, переменные получают значения, но ajax запрос не посылается, но стоит после запроса добавить

```
alert(1);
```

Как всё начинает работать, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы хотите "ajax submit" сделать? А где тогда `.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Извините, я не понял о чём вы:(

Comment: Вы хотите сделать отправку данных скрипту `ban_inter.php` без перезагрузки страницы?

Comment: Да. Я хочу сделать отправку запроса без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(eventObj){
        var id = $("input[name='ik_payment_id']").val();
        var url = $("input[name='url']").val();
        var image = $("input[name='image']").val();
        var plan = $("input[name='plan']").val();

        $.post("ban_inter.php", {cmd:"add_200", id:id, url:url, image:image, plan:plan}, function(){
            alert("Data sent");
        });

        eventObj.preventDefault(); // предотвращает стандартное поведение при отправке формы
    });
});
```

Ещё прочтите про [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)